# Creating two or more sitemesh decorators in struts 2 app?

Tags: struts2, decorator, sitemesh

i am creatig a struts 2 application using sitemesh 2.4 plugin in which i want to apply multiple decorator acording to requested resource.

**decorators.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<decorators defaultdir="/decorators">
<decorator name="layout1" page="layout1.jsp">
    <pattern>/first/*</pattern>
</decorator>
<decorator name="layout" page="layout.jsp">
    <pattern>/second/*</pattern>
</decorator>
 </decorators>
```

i have created to two different layout file named layout.jsp and layout1.jsp inside decorators directory and i have create a navigation file which is like this

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.opensymphony.com/sitemesh/decorator" prefix="decorator" %> 
<decorator:usePage id="thePage" /> 
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<% String selection = thePage.getProperty("meta.selection"); %> 
<p> 
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"> 
<tr> 
    <td> 
        <% if(selection != null && "index".equals(selection)){ %> 
            <a href="first/index.jsp" class="selected">Main</a>
            <%System.out.println(""+selection); %> 
        <% } else { %> 
            <a href="first/index.jsp">Main</a> 
            <%System.out.println("index else"+selection); %>
        <% } %> 
    </td> 

</tr><tr> 
    <td> 
        <% if(selection != null && "page1".equals(selection)){ %> 
            <a href="second/page1.jsp" class="selected">Page 1</a> 
        <% } else { %> 
            <a href="second/page1.jsp">Page 1</a> 
        <% } %> 
    </td> 
</tr>
</table>
```

welcome page(/first/index.jsp) is displayed with layout1 decorator and when i click on "page 1" link it also display with corresponding(layout) decorator. but problem is that when click on Main link after visiting "page 1" it gives "HTTP Status 404 - /StrutsSitemesh/second/first/index.jsp" it's appending the requested resource with previous resource directory. plz help me to get it working

Answer (score 0):

i am using reqest.getContextPath() method inside every link which return the context path of the application and request the resource with absolute path like this----

```
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"> 
<tr> 
<td> 
    <% if(selection != null && "index".equals(selection)){ %> 
        <a href="<%=request.getContextPath() %>/first/index.jsp 
  class="selected">Main</a>
        <%System.out.println(""+selection); %> 
    <% } else { %> 
        <a href="<%=request.getContextPath() %>/first/index.jsp">Main</a> 
        <%System.out.println("index else"+selection); %>
    <% } %> 
</td> 
</tr>
<tr> 
<td> 
    <% if(selection != null && "page1".equals(selection)){ %> 
        <a href="<%=request.getContextPath() %>/second/page1.jsp"
 class="selected">Page 1</a> 
    <% } else { %> 
        <a href="<%=request.getContextPath() %>/second/page1.jsp">Page 1</a> 
    <% } %> 
</td> 
</tr>
</table>
```

if you people have much more productive and effective solution please elaborate.